# How to note the change of file name and file content in a folder

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I recently wrote a winform to notes the changes of number of files in a folder and display a Message when the number of files in two folders are not same.
So I want to improve my program little more by adding codes in such way that.. Is there any way that I should notify when the file name and content is changed.

Which means the total number if files in the both folder will be same. But if I change the file name to a different file name or the content in the file name got deleted or added. In this case what I can do.

Any ideas.
Note I don't want anything to upload to the software the software should do everything automatically...

Thanks a lot...

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` ?

Comment: How you monitor changes in number? With FileSystemWatcher? It has also events for modification and rename. BTW it's impossible that two folders will always be in sync, for a short period of time they MUST differ untill changes are applied to both (so even for #count you may delay your check).

Comment: But can I notify if the file name and content is changed by file watcher

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileSystemWatcher to receive events when something happens to file in a folder.

```
...

FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = // your path to be watched
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
// Only watch text files for example
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

...

// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to code for a file content is changed. what i should write inside `private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{`

Comment: Depends what action you wanna perform when there is a file change

Comment: I just need to notify the change change by a dialog box and copy the file to 2nd folder

Comment: So it's like, one folder to watch (as you said it's correct) and one folder to compare the files and contents inside the watch folder same or not...

Comment: So when a OnChanged event is triggered, do a check from this file with the one located in the other folder. It is hard to know exactly what kind of action do u wanna perform. Do you have a full example in situation